# Excel IF-formula with multiple conditions from 4 columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Got values (people's age) in columns B, C, D and E. I'm trying to get output "2" if age is below 23 or above 67. But I have to take into account that there may be celles present with text and maybe cells holding value 0, or even blank. So I got this formula for column B:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),IF(OR(AND(B2>0,B2<23),B2>67),2,""),"")
```

Formula works, but I want to do the same thing with columns C, D and E - and put it all into one formula. This should have output "2" if any of the 4 columns meet my age-conditions. And my problem is that I clearly don't have the skills to pull this off... Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: Mind posting a screenshot of sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2** - Added support for non-contiguous range.  This is not an array formula"

`=IF(OR(AND(N(B1)>0,N(B1)<23),AND(N(F1)>0,N(F1)<23),AND(N(L1)>0,N(L1)<23),AND(N(X1)>0,N(X1)<23),MAX(B1,F1,L1,X1)>67),2,0)`

***Edited to account for possiblity that all four cells may be text, blank, 0 or a combination of the 3.

Here is an array formula that takes into account the text, blank, and zero cells that may exist in the cells:

`=IF(SUM((B1:E1=0)+ISBLANK(B1:E1)+ISTEXT(B1:E1))>3,0,IF(OR(MAX(IF(B1:E1=0+ISBLANK(B1:E1)+ISTEXT(B1:E1),60,B1:E1))>62,MIN(IF(B1:E1=0+ISBLANK(B1:E1)+ISTEXT(B1:E1),60,B1:E1))<23),2,0))`

Make sure to enter this formula using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I think there's a pretty easy fix for that I can employ. Will update tomorrow in front of comp.

Comment: Had an extra moment, @pnuts. Solved for that possibility I believe.  New formula in edited answer.

Comment: I actually thought I just could use the same formula I already had, and put it in 4 times with a lot of else and If's, I just couldn't figure out how to make it work. But when you guys are suggesting arrays, I have to point out that it's only in my example columns are B, C, D and E. In my real sheet it is B, F, L and X. That makes an array impossible, doesn't it?

Comment: Given the premisis in my question, the formula from @toucansame works just fine! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kit99 I believe theres a way to configure with arrays across non contiguous columns, but in that case a bunch of nested ifs may work better. Happy to take one last look for you today over lunch.

Comment: @kit99, this is a cluster f*** but it works: `=IF(SUM(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))=0+ISBLANK(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"})))+ISTEXT(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))))>3,0,IF(OR(MAX(IF(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))=0+ISBLANK(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"})))+ISTEXT(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))),60,N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))))>62,MIN(IF(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))=0+ISBLANK(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"})))+ISTEXT(N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))),60,N(INDIRECT({"B1","F1","L1","X1"}))))<23),2,0))` No need to use CSE to enter

Comment: The only issue with the above is you can't copy/paste since the cells are in quotes. You could do a find/replace but that too would get tedious. Not a lot of great options here I'm afraid.

Comment: Good god... Rather amazingly :-)  this works just fine in row 1. But as you're saying it's not ideal when it can't be copied down and change row/range automaticly. Thanks again for all your suggestions and help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170314/discussion-between-toucansame-and-kit99).

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter which age is above 67 or below 23 you could use:

```
=IF(OR(MAX(B2:E2)>67,MIN(B2:E2)<23),2,"")
```

Comment: Sorry @cybernetic.nomad, but your suggestion returns "2" when cells don't meet my age-conditions but is blank, is "0" or holds text. And I was trying to avoid that.